# How to resolve dependency issue - Angular14 flex-layout

Tags: angular

I am using Angular14 and tried to install Angular Flex layout.

I am getting this error:
after running the command - `ng add @angular/flex-layout`

```
error Found: @angular/cdk@14.0.2
error node_modules/@angular/cdk
error   @angular/cdk@"^14.0.2" from the root project
error
error Could not resolve dependency:
error peer @angular/cdk@"^13.0.0" from @angular/flex-layout@13.0.0-beta.38
error node_modules/@angular/flex-layout
error   @angular/flex-layout@"13.0.0-beta.38" from the root project
```

So, to use it, do I need to downgrade angular? or there is a workaround to this?

Answer (score 6):

You could also use --legacy-peer-deps

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps @angular/flex-layout
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is still a work in progress: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1404. The github issue claims flex-layout 13 is compatible with angular 14, so you could try to add/update your dependencies by adding the `--force` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14
git add . && git commit -m "wip:core updated"
ng update @angular/material@14 @angular/flex-layout@14.0.0-beta.41
ng version
```

First, update your core modules. Then update material module (in case you use it) and the flex to its angular v14.x.x equivalent.

Note that the git commit is mandatory or you will show an error.

Then check that the versions are okay with `ng version`

Your output will be similar to mine:

```
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cdk @ "14.2.7" (was "13.3.9")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/flex-layout @ "14.0.0-beta.41" (was "13.0.0-beta.38")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/material @ "14.2.7" (was "13.3.9")...
UPDATE package.json (2280 bytes)
✔ Packages successfully installed.
** Executing migrations of package '@angular/cdk' **

▸ Updates the Angular CDK to v14.
    
      ✓  Updated Angular CDK to version 14
    
  Migration completed.

** Executing migrations of package '@angular/material' **

▸ Updates the Angular Material to v14.
    
      ✓  Updated Angular Material to version 14
    
  Migration completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using --legacy-peer-deps or --force will work but not in all cases.  If you need to do a "ng add" command then these will not work and will cause the error to be thrown.  So an update must be provided ASAP

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your v14 question, but this may be helpful to you or others who find this question. I just found out while trying to upgrade to v15 that the Angular team [will no longer be maintaining @angular/flex-layout](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127#:%7E:text=Layout%20has%20made%20significant%20advancements%20since%20Angular%E2%80%99s%20early%20days.%20Based%20on%20advancements%20to%20native%20layout%20solutions%20and%20removal%20of%20support%20for%20IE11%2C%20the%20Angular%20team%20will%20stop%20publishing%20new%20releases%20of%20the%20experimental%20%40angular/flex%2Dlayout%20library%20starting%20in%20v15.).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@angular/cdk@14.0.2` with an older version of `@angular/flex-layout@13.0.0-beta38.  You want to upgrade` flex-layout`to version`14` as well.

> On a completely side note: Angular flex-layout is no longer maintained by the angular official team. It is recommended to switch over to Tailwind CSS.